How to convert mnemonic to Pub key
Ive been playing around SOL rn but I cant get my mnemonic to convert to the correct pub key
It does spit out one keypair but its not correct it is valid tho
here is my code
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from bip_utils Bip39SeedGenerator

def GenPubPriv():
    words = "my 12 word phrase"
    seed = Bip39SeedGenerator(words).Generate()
    keypair = Keypair.from_seed(seed[:32])
    public_key = str(keypair.public_key)
    private_key = keypair.secret_key.hex()
    
    return public_key, private_key, words

print(GenPubPriv())

Is there some different way specific for SOL? I have only read that SOL uses BIP39 as its standart for phrases

You likely need to specify a different derivation path for your words in order to generate the correct public key. Most wallets default to using the 44'/501' beginning. More info at https://docs.solanalabs.com/cli/wallets/paper#hierarchical-derivation
The bip-utils library contains helpers to work with Solana addresses, so you should be able to do:
from bip_utils import Bip39SeedGenerator, Bip39WordsNum, Bip44, Bip44Coins

# Generate seed from mnemonic
seed_bytes = Bip39SeedGenerator(words).Generate()

# The first 32-byte of the seed is the private key
bip44_ctx = Bip44.FromPrivateKey(seed_bytes[:32], Bip44Coins.SOLANA)
# Same address of Solana-CLI
print(f"Address: {bip44_ctx.PublicKey().ToAddress()}")
# Print master key, no need to derive any child key
print(f"Public key: {bip44_ctx.PublicKey().RawCompressed().ToHex()}")

Copied from https://github.com/ebellocchia/bip_utils/blob/master/examples/solana_cli.py

from solana_account_sdk.api import format_mnemonic

words = 'cream bleak tortoise ocean nasty game gift forget fancy salon mimic amazing'
format_account = format_mnemonic(words)
print(format_account)

format_account = format_mnemonic(words, _dpath="m/44'/501'/0'/0'")
print(format_account)

